# Width of Textbox, which placed in grid column, extends when inserting long text

Tags: wpf, xaml

When I put a Textbox in a grid column like below

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="115"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="hello"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" />
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="push me"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

I get proper result, i.e. textbox width is get from parent grid

[image]

But when I type a long text, the textbox starts exceeding its column and it stops extending after several extra letters

[image]

To .Net 4.6.2, I get same result but changing to .Net 4.7.2 the problem is solved i.e. the textbox width is not changing. 
My software is compiled .Net 4.0, is there a solution to solve this for lower .net than 4.7.2?

Tried Pavel's first idea: removing stackpanel and adding another grid row in,  still not working in .net 4.6.2

[image]

Tried Pavel's second idea: making the width of first column "Auto" instead of "1*".  This works, the textbox doesn't extend (.net 4.6.2), however I really wanted the first and second column be responsive to resize.

[image]

Comment: What is the StackPanel used for ? Remove it and it should work as expected

Comment: @NawedNabiZada I removed the stack panel, the problem exists. By the way,  StackPanel is there, so I can have many of this input fields under each other, otherwise one grid fills whole window.

Comment: You can add RowDefinition to your Grid set the HorizontalAlignment of TextBox to Stretch. StackPanel only fills the necessary space and in your case it fills the space needed for TextBox and extends the Grid while you are adding text to the TextBox

Comment: @Sorush you can set the grid row height to auto to fit its content, have a look at my answer

Comment: I amended the dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this be removing the `StackPanel` and adding `RowDefinition` to `Grid`. You can also set `TextWrapping="Wrap"` for `TextBox` for wrapping a long text

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="hello" MinWidth="115"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="push me"/>
    </Grid>
```

`StackPanel` Y dimension is constrained to content, it will be automatically expanded to its content, more details can be found at [panels overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/panels-overview)

Comment: I get same results if  change <ColumnDefinition Width="star" MinWidth="115"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3star"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="95"/>

Comment: @Sorush Updated, behavior is the same. Actually, the first `ColumnDefinition` doesn't make a lot of sense, you can use `Width="Auto"` and restrict the min width of the texblock itself

Comment: Your last edit works by setting first column Width="Auto". But I wanted fields widths to be responsive when window is resized because of that I used width="1star".

Comment: If you restrict the column min or max width, all elements within this column will be affected

Comment: Please see updated question. I voted up your effort as very helpful. But I will wait for other answers.

Comment: I've compiled your sample on .NET 4.6.2 and wasn't able to reproduce it

Comment: Do 2 changes on your code you get mine: 1) move MinWidth="115" from textblock to first columndefinition, 2) for first column definition change Width="Auto" to Width="1*".

Answer (score 0):

To me this is a bug that Textbox text size can change its parent width (grid width). This is happening in VS2019 .Net 4->4.6.2 but not in and after .Net 4.7.2.

For anybody faces this problem, I found below workaround by defining an invisible grid which contains textblocks. I get the widths of columns and give them to controls placed in a StackPanel.

```
 <some container>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition  Width="1*" MinWidth="115"/>
                <ColumnDefinition  Width="3*" />
                <ColumnDefinition  MinWidth="90"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock x:Name="C0" Grid.Column="0" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="C1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="C2" Grid.Column="2" />
        </Grid>


        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Width="{Binding ElementName=C0, Path=ActualWidth }" Text="hello" />
            <TextBox Width="{Binding ElementName=C1, Path=ActualWidth }" Margin="5" />
            <Button Width="{Binding ElementName=C2, Path=ActualWidth }" Content="push me"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </some container>
```

The margin should be the same for column in grid and control in StackPanel (see second column).